# How to hide cmd window while running a batch file?

Tags: c#, process, batch-file

How to hide cmd window while running a batch file?

I use the following code to run batch file

```
process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = batchFilePath;
process.Start();
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute is **false**, then you are launching the process and can use:

```
proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
```

If proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute is **true**, then the OS is launching the process and you have to provide a "hint" to the process via:

```
proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
```

However the called application may ignore this latter request.

If using UseShellExecute = **false**, you might want to consider redirecting standard output/error, to capture any logging produced:

```
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
proc.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(ProcessOutputHandler);
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
proc.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(ProcessOutputHandler);
```

And have a function like

```
private void ProcessOutputHandler(object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs outLine)
{
   if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(outLine.Data)) // use the output outLine.Data somehow;
}
```

There's a good page covering `CreateNoWindow` this on [an MSDN blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/jmstall/archive/2006/09/28/CreateNoWindow.aspx).

There is also a bug in Windows which may throw a dialog and defeat `CreateNoWindow` if you are passing a username/password. For details

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=98476
http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=818858

Comment: Sometimes works, others doesn't. Does this depend on bat file commands?

Comment: Ahmed, I've made the answer more comprehensive and the two different options you have for hiding the window. Also, depending on the application, I think you can still have it break out and make some windows despite your better efforts.

Answer (score 8):

According to the [Process properties](http://dotnetperls.com/process-start-net), you do have a:

> Property: `CreateNoWindow`
>   Notes:    Allows you to run a command line program silently.
>             It does not flash a console window.

and:

> Property: `WindowStyle`
>   Notes:    Use this to set windows as hidden.
>             The author has used `ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden` often.

As an example!

```
static void LaunchCommandLineApp()
{
    // For the example
    const string ex1 = "C:\\";
    const string ex2 = "C:\\Dir";

    // Use ProcessStartInfo class
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    startInfo.FileName = "dcm2jpg.exe";
    startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    startInfo.Arguments = "-f j -o \"" + ex1 + "\" -z 1.0 -s y " + ex2;

    try
    {
        // Start the process with the info we specified.
        // Call WaitForExit and then the using statement will close.
        using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
        {
            exeProcess.WaitForExit();
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        // Log error.
    }
}
```

Comment: Sometimes works, others doesn't. Does this depend on bat file commands?

Answer (score 5):

Use:
    process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

Comment: Sometimes works, others doesn't. Does this depend on bat file commands?

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me,
When you redirect all of the input and output, and set the window hidden it should work

```
            Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

try with [this](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/.net/getCmdPID.bat) and [this](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/.net/c/windowMode.bat) where the c# code is embedded into the batch files:

```
@echo off

echo self minimizing
call getCmdPid.bat
call windowMode.bat -pid %errorlevel% -mode minimized

echo --other commands--
pause
```

Though it might be not so easy to unhide the window.