# Getting output from one executable in an other one

Tags: c#, redirect, executable, console-application

I'm currently trying to get the output of an executable console-app into an other one. To be exact, a little overview of what I'm trying to do:

I have one executable which I cannot edit and neither see it's code. It writes some (quite a bunch to be honest) lines into the console when executed.

Now I want to write another executable that starts the one above and reads the things it writes.

Seems simple to me, so I started coding but ended up with an error message saying that `StandardOut has not been redirected or the process hasn't started yet.`

I tried it using this kinda structure (C#):

```
Process MyApp = Process.Start(@"C:\some\dirs\foo.exe", "someargs");
MyApp.Start();
StreamReader _Out = MyApp.StandardOutput;

string _Line = "";

while ((_Line = _Out.ReadLine()) != null)
    Console.WriteLine("Read: " + _Line);

MyApp.Close();
```

I can open the executable and it also does open the one inside, but as soon as it comes to reading the returned values, the app crashes.

What am I doing wrong?!

Comment: You may be interested in my answer against this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096591/how-to-hide-cmd-window-while-running-a-batch-file/1096626#1096626

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation for the [Process.StandardOutput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput.aspx) property. You will need to set a boolean indicating that you want the stream redirected as well as disabling shell execute.

Note from the documentation:

> To use StandardOutput, you must set ProcessStartInfo..::.UseShellExecute to false, and you must set ProcessStartInfo..::.RedirectStandardOutput to true. Otherwise, reading from the StandardOutput stream throws an exception

You would need to change your code a little bit to adjust for the changes:

```
Process myApp = new Process(@"C:\some\dirs\foo.exe", "someargs");
myApp.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
myApp.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;

myApp.Start();

string output = myApp.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
p.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: That was fast... sorry for not trying TFM first :( Will do better next time

Answer (score 2):

you could try setting [`processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

As noted above, you can use RedirectStandardOutput as [here](http://dotnetperls.com/process-redirect-standard-output).

Another, dirtier way is something like

```
using (Process child = Process.Start
  ("cmd", @"/c C:\some\dirs\foo.exe someargs > somefilename"))
  {
    exeProcess.WaitForExit();
  }
```

And then read its output from *somefilename*