# How to get the output of a process?

Tags: c#, stdout

I am open WireShark using command line and start capture the packets, when i do it using CMD windows i can see the number of the incoming packets and this number i want to show in my application form (win form), currently this is my code but my application crash with error

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        string _pcapPath = @"C:\test.pcap";
        Process _tsharkProcess = new Process();
        _tsharkProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\Wireshark\tshark.exe";
        _tsharkProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format(" -i " + 2 + " -c " + int.MaxValue + " -w " + _pcapPath);
        _tsharkProcess.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(process_OutputDataReceived);
        _tsharkProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        _tsharkProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        //_tsharkProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        //_tsharkProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        _tsharkProcess.Start();
        StreamReader myStreamReader = _tsharkProcess.StandardOutput;
        string myString = myStreamReader.ReadLine(); //read the standard output of the spawned process. 
        Console.WriteLine(myString);
        _tsharkProcess.WaitForExit();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

    }

}

private static void process_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    string srt = e.Data; //arg.Data contains the output data from the process...  
}
```

Comment: so post for the error cause- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700695/getting-output-from-one-executable-in-an-other-one

Comment: Did you try setting `RedirectStandardOutput` before calling `process.Start()`?

Comment: OK now it's ok after setting RedirectStandardOutput and UseShellExecute before process.Start() but how can i get the output of my process ? now the opened CMD windows empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with this code

Nota : Set these lines before start

```
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            process.Start();
```

Code:

```
            Process process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\Wireshark\tshark.exe";
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format(" -i " + _interfaceNumber + " -c " + int.MaxValue + " -w " + _pcapPath);
            process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(process_OutputDataReceived);

            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;


       process.Start();

            StreamReader myStreamReader = process.StandardOutput;
            // Read the standard output of the spawned process. 
            string myString = myStreamReader.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(myString);

            process.WaitForExit();
            process.Close();
        }
```

Comment: i canon't reach the line string myString = myStreamReader.ReadLine(); even after create break point, it seems that after process.Start(); it is all stuck (but the process working and create the file with the packets on the disk)

Comment: it's possible that you must wait an moment for executing your treatment

Comment: i did not understand what do you mean

Comment: i update my code with my present code and still nothing, only the cmd windows that show me the number of packets received