# Two commands on a process

Tags: c#, process

I have an exe which I can run in console like below

```
util.exe argument1
```

I need to invoke this from a CSharp application which I can do like below

```
  private string Command(string arg)
  {
            var p = new Process
            {
                StartInfo =
                {
                    FileName = "util.exe",
                    Arguments = arg,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    RedirectStandardInput = true,
                    CreateNoWindow = true,
                    UseShellExecute = false
                }
            };

            var stdOutput = new StringBuilder();
            p.OutputDataReceived += (sender, args) => stdOutput.AppendLine(args.Data);

            p.Start();
            p.BeginOutputReadLine();
            p.WaitForExit();

            return stdOutput.ToString();
 }


 var result = Command(argument1) //call
```

However there is an issue. util.exe authenticates user using the Windows logged in credentials. In the application I need to execute the commands as a different user(Like below)

```
 util.exe login funcationaluser fuucntioanluserpwd
 util.exe argument1
```

What is the right way for doing this? Can I reuse the process?

Edit: Please note the username and password is specific to util.exe , not a system username/password

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run .bat file through C# code as different user silently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650738/run-bat-file-through-c-sharp-code-as-different-user-silently)

Comment: Another duplicate would be this [Start a .Net Process as a different user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624113/start-a-net-process-as-a-different-user)

Comment: It is not logging in as a different windows user. The user name and password is specific to the exe to be executed(util.exe)

Comment: ah, so it takes in credentials as arguments?  So are you asking how to write a method that will do both the login command and the argument1 command?

Comment: @Hack yes that is the intention

Comment: Perhaps I need to invoke cmd.exe?

Comment: After getting a few more details the answer I posted won't work for you so I deleted it.  I've done what your asking before, but its been years so i'd have to do a little bit of a refresher to remember how i did it before.  If this hasn't been answered later today I may post a better answer later.