# How to open a .bat file without showing the dialog?

Tags: c#

I tried this :

```
Process CMDprocess = new Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo StartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
StartInfo.FileName = "cmd"; //starts cmd window
StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false; //required to redirect
CMDprocess.StartInfo = StartInfo;
CMDprocess.Start();
System.IO.StreamReader SR = CMDprocess.StandardOutput;
System.IO.StreamWriter SW = CMDprocess.StandardInput;
SW.WriteLine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\my_bat.bat");
```

But it shows me the `.bat` window and the `.bat` file is open another C++ application.

How can I not show the window ?

Comment: Take a look here, 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096591/how-to-hide-cmd-window-while-running-a-batch-file