# Can't hide CMD window while running .bat file using C#

Tags: c#, batch-file, cmd

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            lbl_startingTest.Text = "Flashing DUT..";
            lbl_Result.Text = "Flash";
            
            Process fls1 = new Process();
            fls1.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            fls1.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\test\\test\\bin\\Debug\\flash.bat";
            fls1.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            fls1.Start();
            fls1.WaitForExit();
        }
```

I tried to use fls1.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden; to see if it hides CMD window. But when I run the application software it pops up CMD window when I click button on application. How can I hide the CMD window and still run .bat file in background?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to hide cmd window while running a batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096591/how-to-hide-cmd-window-while-running-a-batch-file)

Answer (score 0):

Try it without UseShellExecute = false; maybe change it to UseShellExecute to true.

```
 private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        lbl_startingTest.Text = "Flashing DUT..";
        lbl_Result.Text = "Flash";
        fls1.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
        Process fls1 = new Process();
        fls1.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\test\\test\\bin\\Debug\\flash.bat";
        fls1.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        fls1.Start();
        fls1.WaitForExit();
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

The [`CreateNoWindow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.createnowindow?view=net-7.0#system-diagnostics-processstartinfo-createnowindow) property might be what you are looking for.

`fls1.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;`

Comment: Extremely brief answers like this are usually downvoted and often removed.  Consider fleshing it out more with some context and reasoning behind your suggestion.